# Finding a smooth function

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find a smooth function $f$ such that $f>0$ on $(1,2)$ and $f=0$ otherwise. Here is how I think the graph -purple- might look due of the smoothness.
[image]

The only example that comes to mind is $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}.$ Since this example is never 0, is there a smooth way to make it 0 outside of the unit interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How smooth does it have to be? $C^\infty$? If so, the prototypical example is $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x}&x>0,\\0&x\le0.\end{cases}$$
From this, many similar functions can be built.

Comment: This will not be 0 outside of (0,1).

Comment: That is what the final remark is for (I should perhaps have said “building block” instead of “example”). Consider $f(x)f(1-x)$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually called a bump function, which you can read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Comment: Verifying that these various formulas give a smooth function at the boundary between the zero and non-zero parts is a good exercise in induction.